# SwiftUI input text in the center of the text field

Tags: swift, swiftui

this is my first time working with SwiftUI and unfortunately I am currently failing to implement something like keeping the text in my textfield centered.
My code looks like this:

```
TextField("some text", text: $text)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

This also works so far, but when the user enters a text, it is no longer centered.
It's a tvOS app if that's important.
[image: The placeholder text is correctly centered]

[image: When the user enters text]

Comment: On iOS it's still centered

Comment: mmh ok, when I click on the text field, keyboard view opens and when I press "Done" there, the console gives me the following: "Snapshotting a view (0x7fef6a025e00, UIKeyboardImpl) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates: YES". I don't know maybe it has anything to do with it?

Comment: Not likely. That happens all the time with SwiftUI, you can ignore it.